# how to import the blog.py(i import the 'blog' folder)

Tags: python, import

my dir location,i am in a.py:

```
my_Project
     |----blog
            |-----__init__.py
            |-----a.py
            |-----blog.py
```

when i 'from blog import something' in a.py , it show error:

```
from blog import BaseRequestHandler
ImportError: cannot import name BaseRequestHandler
```

i think it import the blog folder,not the blog.py

so how to import the blog.py

**updated**

when i use 'blog.blog', it show this:

```
from blog.blog import BaseRequestHandler
ImportError: No module named blog
```

**updated2**

my sys.path is :

```
['D:\\zjm_code', 'D:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', 'D:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\whoosh-0.3.18-py2.5.egg', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python25.zip', 'D:\\Python25\\DLLs', 'D:\\Python25\\lib', 'D:\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win', 'D:\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk', 'D:\\Python25', 'D:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages', 'D:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']


zjm_code
    |-----a.py
    |-----b.py
```

a.py is :

```
c="ccc"
```

b.py is :

```
from a import c
print c
```

and when i execute b.py ,i show this:

```
> "D:\Python25\pythonw.exe"  "D:\zjm_code\b.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\b.py", line 2, in <module>
    from a  import c
ImportError: cannot import name c
```

Comment: I missed the bit about where you were doing the import. It's definitely not importing the `blog` module. What's in `blog.py`?

Answer (score 1):

When you are in `a.py`, `import blog` should import the local `blog.py` and nothing else. Quoting the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> modules are searched in the list of directories given by the variable sys.path which is initialized from the directory containing the input script

So my guess is that somehow, the name `BaseRequestHandler` is not defined in the file `blog.py`.

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you:

```
import blog
```

Try outputting your sys.path, in order to make sure that you have the right dir to call the module from.